# Get Timeout Error on Firebase Functions when calling external API in functions

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Functions

Everything works perfectly except for a few issues

Some requests that worked flawlessly before are now giving a timeout error

I mean,

I am making an http post request using "axios" from within the firebase functions (outbound or external request, whatever it is called )

When I run it with the emulator, the codes work correctly, although I see that my http requests are working correctly, when I deploy the firebase function, I see that the same requests get timeouts.

By the way I'm using the Blaze plan.

However,

The code I get the timeout is as follows:

```
var getToken = async () => {

    var link = configLink("GENERAL") + "CreateTokenV2";
    try {
        var result = await axios.post(link, {

            "channelCredential": {
                "ChannelCode": _CONFIG.TENANT.ChannelCode,
                "ChannelPassword": _CONFIG.TENANT.ChannelPassword,

            }

        });

        var ds = result.data;
        if (ds.HasError) {
            console.log(ds.ErrorMessage);
            return false;
        }

        await insertHelper("kplus", {
            url: _CONFIG.url,
            channelcode: _CONFIG.TENANT.ChannelCode,
            channelpassword: _CONFIG.TENANT.ChannelPassword,
            token: ds.Result.TokenCode,
            lastdate: new Date(ds.Result.ExpiresAt),
            tokenobject: ds.Result
        })
        return ds.Result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return new Error(err);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any code snippets or screenshots to help us understand what exactly is not working properly?

Comment: Sure.I will share with edit

Comment: How and where are you calling `getToken()`? This looks like a case of improper function lifecycle handling. Once a deployed function has been marked inactive, resources will be severely throttled and networking blocked. The emulators don't simulate this which is why your code works locally.

Comment: @samthecodingman What should I do ?

Comment: @HüseyinOkumuş Edit in how and where you are calling `getToken()`.